# Controlling a table's primary key value when running On Conflict command

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Got a table that I need to populate data while getting rid of duplicates. Am using `ON CONFLICT ... DO NOTHING`. Issue is, when the table has an auto_increment primary_key field -lets call it `id`-, it seems that that field continues to increase even when duplicates are not inserted resorting to the `id` field value being way higher than the number of records that have successfully been inserted.

Unfortunately SQL Fiddle does not currently support postgresql 9.5 so I'll copy paste the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
    id    serial primary key,
    col_foo        VARCHAR(40) not null unique,
    col_bar        VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT into table_one (col_foo, col_bar) 
VALUES ('1a', '1b'), ('2a', '2b'), ('1a', '2b'),('1a', Null), ('3a', '1b'), ('4a', '2b'), ('1a', '2b'),('1a', Null) 
ON CONFLICT (col_foo) DO NOTHING;
```

If you run that on postgresql 9.5, you'll find that the final primary key is 6 while there are only 4 records. Is it possible to ensure that if 4 records out of 6 are successfully inserted then the max/last id field should have a value of 4?

In my current case, I was dealing with a large data set which had 1.2 million records inserted but the very last record had an id value of 62 million. That's what i'm trying to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course use a temp table to catch&suppress the duplicates:

```
CREATE TABLE table_one
(
    id    serial primary key,
    col_foo        VARCHAR(40) not null unique,
    col_bar        VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_one
(
    id    serial primary key, -- dont actually need this
    col_foo        VARCHAR(40) not null unique,
    col_bar        VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT into temp_one (col_foo, col_bar)
VALUES ('1a', '1b'), ('2a', '2b'), ('1a', '2b'),('1a', Null), ('3a', '1b'), ('4a', '2b'), ('1a', '2b'),('1a', Null)
ON CONFLICT (col_foo) DO NOTHING
        ;

INSERT into table_one (col_foo, col_bar)
SELECT col_foo, col_bar FROM temp_one
ON CONFLICT (col_foo) DO NOTHING -- wont need this
         -- (except for suppressing already-existing duplicates)
        ;

SELECT * FROM temp_one;
SELECT * FROM table_one;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not really change the behavior of ON CONFLICT. All it allows is updating the conflicting row instead of creating a new one.

You can reset the sequence and reassign the IDs afterwards, though:

```
SELECT setval('table_one_id_seq', 1);
UPDATE table_one SET id = nextval('table_one_id_seq');
```

And, of course, you should never rely on last ID to get the row count. And if you are worried about running out of IDs, use bigserial instead of serial.